# unused-variable warning is raised not for all unused static const variables

Tags: c++, unused-variables

Could you help me to understand why I get unused-variable warning not for all unused static const variables?
I prepared a simple code. Here are 2 files main.cpp and incl.h.

## incl.h

```
#ifndef INCL_H
#define INCL_H

struct A 
{
    static A& instance()
    {
        static A a;
        return a;
    }
};

static const A a = A::instance();
static const A& b = A::instance();

#endif
```

## main.cpp

```
#include "incl.h"

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that there will be 2 unused-variable warnings (for a and b fariables), but in fact the warning is only one for variable **b**.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -O2 -c main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
incl.h:14:17: warning: ‘b’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static const A& b = A::instance();
```

Why doesn't the variable **a** cause the same warning?

Comment: I think you will see the same phenomenon with any class type.

Comment: Which version of g++ ser you using?

Comment: @Jonas, g++ version is 5.4.1

Answer (score 1):

For variable a the singleton instance is copied into the variable by assignment, so you could argue that it is being used.

Comment: Ok, let's concider that variable a is being used becuse it is created by copying. I propose to change variable b definition to "static const A& b = a;". In this case there will not be any warnings at all. Where is using varible b? Also I can create varible a by "static const A a = A();" And there also won't be warning for a.

Comment: I suppose that it happen due to optimization during compilation. If compiler sees object creation and the variable is not used then the compiler removes it. That is why we don't see the warning otherwise the variable is kept and warning is raised. But it's only my supposition. What do you think about it?